# div com profundidade

Tags: javascript, html

opa, gostaria de saber como faco para criar uma div pra scrollar com o mouse (tipo a do google maps) poderiam me ajudar?
link pra vizualicao abaixo:
https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Brasil/@9.2383701,-79.1770257,3z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x9c59c7ebcc28cf:0x295a1506f2293e63!8m2!3d-14.235004!4d-51.92528!16zL20vMDE1ZnI?entry=ttu

Answer (score -4, accepted):

A maneira de interceptar o scroll do mouse é através do evento `wheel`. Através dele você consegue detectar se o scroll foi rodado para cima ou para baixo e fazer o que desejar com isso.

Neste exemplo, o scroll controla o tamanho da fonte da div:

```js
document.getElementById("bloco").addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);

let font_size = 16;
function onWheel() {
  if (event.wheelDelta > 0) {
    font_size++;
  } else {
    font_size--;
  }
  document.getElementById("bloco").style.fontSize = font_size + "px";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#bloco {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="bloco">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Note que isso não impede que o scroll da página continue funcionando, então o comportamento pode ficar estranho.

Enfim, esse é o básico de como interceptar o scroll do mouse.

Comment: Bacana, só um adendo sobre "Note que isso não impede que o scroll da página continue funcionando, então o comportamento pode ficar estranho.". Dá para adicionar o evento como parâmetro da função onWheel e usar [evento.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: Você também pode tentar dessa maneira: https://jsfiddle.net/34nqcora/